# Object to double conversion error

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write an object to double converter for a Big Integer program by overloading the double conversion operator. To do this I converted the big integer to a string which I then converted to a double using the stod function. Here is a copy of the function:

```
BigInteger::operator double () {
    std::string *str = new std::string[this->m_digitCount];
    for (int j = 0; j < this->m_digitCount; j++) {
        str[j] = this->getDigit(j);
    }
    double a = std::stod(*str);
    return a;
}
```

Just for clarification m_digitCount is the number of digits in a given object.

When I run the program, it crashes and says 'abort() has been called.'

I inserted a break point and found the program crashes at the line

```
double a = std::stod(*str)
```

When this happens it says

Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFB1DEF7788 in Assign4 - Big Integer.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::invalid_argument at memory location 0x00000043F48FD780.

Could someone help me find the problem? Thank you very much.

Comment: well it sounds like the string does not contain a valid number and so the conversion has thrown an exception that you have not caught. WHat does str contain?

Comment: You made an array of `std::string`s, one for each digit.  All you need is one `std::string`, don't use `new` to construct it, then append your digits with something like `str += getDigit(j);`.

Comment: @ChristopherOicles you are right - I didnt even notice. How did this even compile? I guess the real code forcibly casts *str to something that will compile

Comment: @pm100 It is valid code, in fact I'm not really sure why it crashes -- each element in the array of `std::string`s is set to one of the bignum's digits (each a single character in length).  Then `std::stod(*str)` just references the first element in the array.  So it's completely wrong for sure, but `*str` should be a valid object, unless maybe `m_digitCount` is zero?

Comment: @ChristopherOicles you are right it will read the first string (I was thinking of vector of strings nor real old fashioned array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't do what you think it does:

```
std::string *str = new std::string[this->m_digitCount];
```

That allocates an array of empty strings.  I don't know how your code even compiles.

Anyway, what you meant to do was this:

```
std::string str;
str.reserve( m_digitCount );
for (int j = 0; j < m_digitCount; j++) {
    str.push_back( getDigit(j) );
}
return std::stod(str);
```

Note that the digit should be a character type.  If it's just an integer from 0 to 9, you will have to do `str.push_back( '0' + getDigit(j) )`